# Como sumar desde la hora UTC sin que se pase de 24 al mostrar la hora, y lo mismo en la resta

Tags: javascript

```
export function checkHour1(h, sign){
switch (j) {
  case 0:
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h)
  break;
  case 1:
    b++;
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h)
  break;
  case 2:
    b+=2 ;
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h)
  break;
  case 3:
    b+=3;
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h)
  break;
  case 4:
    b+=4;
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h) 
  break;
  case 5:
    b+=5;
    if(sign === "-")return rest(b,h)
    if(sign === "+")return add(h)
  break;
  default:  
  if(sign === "-")return rest(j,h)
  if(sign === "+")return add(h)
    break;
}}
```

Este es el método para sumar o restar desde la hora UTC, lo hice así ya que al momento de sumar o restar y al momento de imprimir la hora, por ejemplo: si en UTC son las 01AM, al momento de restar - 5 horas o (cualquier hora) sale la resta como un entero(por así decirlo, ya que no cambia a formato Date) que el resultado es -4 y lo tuve que cambiar con una variable que comience con 24 y va sumando, pero es algo tedioso el hacerlo manualmente, lo intente con un ciclo, pero no me resulta. Alguna recomendación?

```
let createDate = new Date("March 25, 2023 20:00:00");
let j = createDate.getHours();
let k = createDate.getMinutes();
let m ;
let b = 24;
```

createDate es una hora ficticia para probar con la funcion que estoy haciendo. La "b" es la hora para restar desde "24"

```
function rest(b,h){
return m = b - h  }
```

La funcion restar y la m contiene el resultado.

Comment: Para mostar la hora de Mexico(yo soy de Ecuador, estoy haciendo un reloj mundial), estoy teniendo como modelo la hora del meridiano (UTC), para así restar o sumar con una hora(horaUTC - 5 (aquí mostraría la hora de mexico)). Todo bien hasta ahí, pero al momento que la hora UTC pasa las 00, resta 0 - 5, que sale como resultado -5.. La función que estoy haciendo es pasar filtros al momento que llegue a 0 horas y con la ayuda de una variable (en este caso "b"(que comienza en 24) reste 24 - 5 y ahí sale 19:00hrs en mexico, solo que es algo tedioso hacer para suma o resta lo mismo que dije.

Comment: hay una librería que la recomiendo y es momentjs https://momentjs.com/ , es para JavaScript, es muy completa y es fácil de usa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar la hora según la región lo más simple es usar [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/date/tolocaletimestring) y agregar el argumento `timezone`

```js
let createDate = new Date( "March 25, 2023 20:00:00" );

console.log(createDate.toLocaleTimeString("es",{timeZone : "Australia/Sydney"}));
console.log(createDate.toLocaleTimeString("es",{timeZone : "MST"}));
console.log(createDate.toLocaleTimeString("es",{timeZone : "EST"}));
```

Por otro lado para sumar y restar horas puedes usar la función [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), con lo cual siempre te respetará las 24 horas

```js
let createDate = new Date( "March 25, 2023 20:00:00" );

console.log(createDate)
createDate.setHours(createDate.getHours() - 37);
console.log(createDate)
```

Comment: Gracias brooo, 2 maneras de hacer la función, buenos códigos hermano :), se entendió tu código y el o ella Marce Puente

Answer (score 2):

si lo que necesitas es modificar un objeto Date, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```js
let createDate = new Date( "March 25, 2023 20:00:00" );
createDate.setHours( createDate.getHours() + 24 );
console.log( createDate.getFullYear() );
console.log( createDate.getMonth() );
console.log( createDate.getDate() );
console.log( createDate.getHours() );

createDate.setFullYear( createDate.getFullYear() - 1 );
console.log( createDate.getFullYear() );
```

A la hora de imprimir el resultado, hay que tener en cuenta, que los meses, van del "0" al "11", osea que Enero va a ser representado por un cero, Febrero por un uno, etc...

PD: los otros métodos:

```
setFullYear( createDate.getFullYear() - 1 );
setMonth( createDate.getMonth() + 10 );
setDate( createDate.getDate() + 10 );
setMinutes( createDate.getMinutes() + 10 );
setSeconds( createDate.getSeconds() + 10 );
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte manito, pero eso no es la duda, en el comentario de arriba, aclaré un poco mas las cosas, espero me entiendas mejor :)

Comment: Hola Karlo, si partis de la hora UTC 23, Marzo, 2022, 23:50:00 y haces: **fecha.setHours( fecha.getHours() -1 );**, te va a devolver 23, Marzo, 2022, 22:50:00, que es la hora del meridiano anterior, si en cambio haces: **fecha.setHours( fecha.getHours() +1 );**, te va a devolver 24, Marzo, 2022, 00:50:00, osea la fecha que tiene el meridiano siguiente, y fijate  que ajusta todo, si vos le sumas 8760 horas, te va a sumar un año, y vas a ver las mismas horas, ahora bien, si eso no es lo que necesitas, realmente tendrías que explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Gracias brodersitooo, esa era la duda, gracias de todo corazón :) y buenos códigos :)

Comment: Un placer ayudarte ídolo!!